# What is the right way to reset a timeout?

Tags: javascript, timeout

so I have a function like this:

```
function blabla(){
    ...

    setTimeout(() => {
        //do some stuff
    }, 10000) 
}
```

now How can I reset the time of the timeout (`10000`) if function was called and timeout was not finished yet?
I tried to kill the timeout if it does exist like this:

```
function blabla(){
    ...

    if(to){
       clearTimeout(to)
    } 

    let to = setTimeout(() => {
        //do some stuff
    }, 10000) 
}
```

but I get error that `to` is undefined. so what is the right way to check if a timeout exists or not. is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need declare `to` before the `if`, so that it exists when the `if` runs (and there is not undefined). You don't have to give it an actual value until later.

Realistically, you probably want to declare it outside the function, so it will persist next time you call the function.

Here's a runnable demo. Notice that despite calling blablah() twice, you only see "hello" once, because the second call to the function cancelled the original timeout.

```js
var to;

function blabla() {
  //...

  if (to) {
    clearTimeout(to)
  }

  to = setTimeout(() => {
    //do some stuff
    console.log("hello");
  }, 10000)
}

blabla();
blabla();
```

Answer (score 1):

dont use `let`, `let` scope is inside the function block.
if you call the function the second time, the function does not have let to defined.
use `var` so it is accessible within across function call.

Answer (score 0):

Not good idea use global var for that, because it is not reusable.
Better write wrapper for that function, because it is common pattern. This native code or use npm packet for that

> Debounce functions are included in many JavaScript libraries. The goal
>   behind each implementation is to reduce overhead by preventing a
>   function from being called several times in succession. Regardless of
>   the library, all debounce functions are built on JavaScript's native
>   setTimeout function.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce:

```js
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    let timeout;
    return function() {
        let context = this,
            args = arguments;
        let later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        let callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};

var blabla = debounce(function(){
     console.log(5)
}, 5000);
blabla()
blabla()
```

Comment: most of this seemingly random example is completely irrelevant to the actual question, and since you didn't explain any of it, how is anyone who doesn't already know the answer supposed to guess which part is important for solving the problem being asked about?

Comment: He just need cancel previous function before them will be completed, this common debounce

Comment: Ok thanks. At least there's a runnable example now. But other than saying "this is better", you still haven't really explained what the code is doing, or why it's different to the code in the question. Bear in mind that your code is comparatively complicated, and therefore needs clarification. If you can do that, you'll get my upvote, because I can already see it's a good solution with nice encapsulation, but I think that the OP or other readers with less JS experience might not understand it immediately.